# diferencia en dias de fecha de una columna SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

actualmente tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la cual es un plan de pago de un credito, lo que quiero es un campo que diga DIAS el cual me cuente los dias guiandose del numero de pago, si el numero de pago es 1, entonces que me haga la diferencia de dias entre la fecharegistro y la fechapago, y ya después que haga la diferencia entre unicamente la fechapago

este es el resultado que quiero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el script que utilizo

```
SELECT NumeroRegistro, FechaInicioRegistro,NumeroPago,FechaPago
FROM PLANPAGO
WHERE NumeroRegistro='00800242447'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr eso, es relativamente sencillo usando la función `LAG()`. Con esa función podemos obtener el valor de una fila anterior indicando la columna, la cantidad de filas que hay que recorrer y un default en caso de que sea el primer valor del grupo.

```
SELECT *,
    /*Descomentar para mostrar la fecha usada en el cálculo*/
    --LAG( FechaPago, 1, FechaInicioRegistro) OVER( PARTITION BY NumeroRegistro ORDER BY NumeroPago) FechaAnterior,
    DATEDIFF( DD, LAG( FechaPago, 1, FechaInicioRegistro) OVER( PARTITION BY NumeroRegistro ORDER BY NumeroPago), FechaPago) AS Dias
FROM PLANPAGO
WHERE NumeroRegistro = '00800242447';
```